# With a season pass, can you download dlcs that already came out

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I want to buy the Assassin's creed Tiranny of King Washington dlcs but I'm wondering if I could, if I bought the season pass now, download it with the season pass and even get the Hidden Secrets dlc?

Comment: I don't have this particular game, but Season Pass is generally a license to all listed DLC regardless of whether you buy it before or after the DLC comes out

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, you just saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

Yep, if you buy the season pass now, you are able to download all previous pieces of DLC included with the season pass.

Source: I have the AC3 Season Pass.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, one more question: If I have one of the things in Hidden Secrets from the pre-order. If I buy Hidden Secrets will it bug or something?

Comment: Nope. I had a few things that were in Hidden Secrets as well (the Gamestop preorder exclusives specifically) and never saw any hiccups because of that.